# WordPress REST API Custom Endpoint with URL Parameter

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to create a custom endpoint for the WordPress REST API and pass parameters through the URL.

The endpoint currently is:

`/wp-json/v1/products/81838240219`

What I am trying to achieve is an endpoint that looks like this and being able to retrieve the identifier parameter in the callback.

```
/wp-json/v1/products?identifier=81838240219

// Custom api endpoint test
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
  $identifier = get_query_var( 'identifier' );
  return $identifier;
}
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'api/v1', '/products=(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

First you need to pass in the **namespace** to `register_rest_route`

Like this

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'namespace/v1', '/product/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```

Your name space `namespace/v1` and your route is `/product/{id}` like this 
*/namespace/v1/product/81838240219*

and now you can use the route inside your function like this

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    $product_ID = $data['id'];
}
```

If you need to add options for ex.
*/namespace/v1/product/81838240219?name=Rob*

and use it inside the function like this

```
function my_awesome_func( $data ) {
    $product_ID = $data['id'];
    $name = $data->get_param( 'name' );
}
```

The process is very simple but requires you to read this [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 16):

I modified the provided answer a little to get my desired endpoint:

/wp-json/api/v1/product?identifier=81838240219

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
register_rest_route( 'api/v1', '/product/', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'ea_get_product_data',
    ) );
} );

function ea_get_product_data( $data ) {
    $identifier = $data->get_param( 'identifier' );
    return $identifier;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to pass alphanumeric parameters, use `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` instead of `\d`

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'namespace/v1', '/product/(?P<id>[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
    ) );
} );
```